# Sitecore Login statistics

Tags: authentication, statistics, sitecore

Is there a way to programmatically get login information about a certain user?

The information I need is number of logins between two dates and the last login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the default .NET Membership from Sitecore. The last login is stored in the .NET Membership SQL table.

```
var membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(user.Name, false);
var createdate = string.Empty;
var lastlogin = string.Empty;
if (membershipUser != null)
{
  createdate = membershipUser.CreationDate.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd");
  lastlogin = membershipUser.LastLoginDate.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd");
}
```

As far as I know there is no detailed insight into login information, you have to program it yourself. But a Login is logged in the Sitecore log file. (look at the [Sitecore-Audit-Trail](http://klpatil.github.io/Sitecore-Audit-Trail/) module)

Comment: Gave this a try. It works for many users, but for many users the last login Date returned is "01.01.0001", where I know they recently logged in. What does 01.01.0001 mean?

Comment: Not seen before that the login date is not set after a login. And with user you mean a Sitecore CMS user, login into the Sitecore CMS?.. (inside the Sitecore User Manager, tab Information, you can see the dates, it is there also wrong)

Comment: Edit: Just found out that those values actually come from the system. It seems the dates on the system aren't updated. How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore uses classical ASP.NET Membership, so that information on login count does not present in core database by default.

If you need to do own implementation of desired behaviour, you would:

1. extend user profile with an integer field for logins count;
2. On every user login increment that value.

Read more about how to create and use **Sitecore users custom profile properties**: [link 1](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/sitecore-users-custom-profile-properties/) and [link 2](http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2014/04/07/sitecore-custom-user-profile-properties/)

For incrementing I would probably advise to implement custom processor under **loggedin** pipeline.